# Angular 6 restrict certain alphabets

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have the following input field. I am trying to only allow a user to enter alphabets from A-F. If the user tries to enter an alphabet outside of the range then the alphabet should be trimmed on the fly i.e there is no button to verify if its valid input or not. The input field also allows numbers and special characters.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="MACAddressInput()" placeholder="MAC address" name="mac_address" required [(ngModel)]="model.mac_address" (blur)="validate()">
  <mat-error *ngFor="let error of errors_by_field['mac_address']">{{error.message}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

  MACAddressInput() {
    if (this.model.mac_address) {
      const inputColon = this.model.mac_address.replace(new RegExp(':', 'g'), '').trim();
      const MAC_blocks = inputColon.match(/.{1,2}/g);
      let formatedMac = MAC_blocks.shift();
      for (const block of MAC_blocks) {
       formatedMac = formatedMac + ':' + block;
      }
      this.model.mac_address = formatedMac.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
```

I tried with html patterns but it allows a user to input anything

Comment: I would use reactive forms and Validators for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `custom pipe` to do that.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myCustomPipe'
  })
  export class MyCustomPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(input: string): string {
        let newString = "";
      for(let i=0; i<= input.length; i++){
        var char = input.charAt(i);
        if(char.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && char.charCodeAt(0) <=70){
            newString += char;
        }
      }

      return newString;
    }
  }
```

Then add it into your module

```
 declarations: [
    ...
    MyCustomPipe,
    ...
]
```

Call it into your .html component in this way

```
{{ myText | myCustomPipe }}
```

I've done a test, with `myText = "ABCG";` my pipe trimmed the text to `ABC`.

To do the magic inside your function:

```
if (this.model.mac_address) {
    let newString = "";
    for(let i=0; i<= this.model.mac_address.length; i++){
        var char = this.model.mac_address.charAt(i);
        if(char.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && char.charCodeAt(0) <=70){
            newString += char;
        }
    }
    this.model.mac_address = newString.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: thanks but how would I append the pipe to the html, If you look at the html code I provided there is no {{mytext}}

Comment: I have added my ts code function which does some input formatting as it is for a MAC Address

Comment: In regards to using a pipe, you could try: ```[ngModel]="model.mac_address | myCustomPipe" (ngModelChange)="model.mac_address=$event"```. It would just pipe the text input before assigning it to the model.

Comment: Pipe are intended to to that work. Anyway I've edited my answer and posted the code to do the pipe logic into your function

Comment: @eohdev I think the issue with doing it on keyup is that there is a risk of delay before the value changes in your input field. At least from my experience, this has happened before.

Comment: @Wingnod it seems ok here, I'll keep it in mind though

Comment: @eohdev That's good. Maybe I've been doing it wrong this entire time :)

Answer (score 2):

Incase if you want to do it with simple binding function

**Code**:

```
MACAddressInput(e) {
   let code = e.key.charCodeAt(0);
   if ((code >= 65 && code <= 90) || (code >= 97 && code <= 122)) {}
   else {
     e.preventDefault();
     return;
   }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<input matInput (keydown)="MACAddressInput($event)" placeholder="MAC address" name="mac_address" required [(ngModel)]="model.mac_address" (blur)="validate()">
```

**Note** : Make sure you use `(keydown)` event. This code will allow A-Z and a-z.